# ¿Dónde se usa "¿qué pasó?" como fórmula de saludo?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, saludos

Mis abuelos maternos eran de Tenerife. Solían utilizar "¿qué pasó?" en el momento de saludar a alguien. Lo he oído también a otras personas cuando he estado en esa isla, con el significado de "¿qué tal?", "¿cómo va?" o "¿cómo estás?". Por ejemplo, recuerdo una respuesta típica de mi abuela cuando la llamaba por teléfono:

> ¿Qué hay, Charito? ¿Qué pasó?

De lo de "Charito" hay que darle la culpa a esa manía que había antes de ponerle a los hijos los mismos nombres que sus padres: mi madre también era Charo. Entonces, para distinguirme, yo era Charito. Bueno, cuando escuchaba esas palabras de mi abuela, me daban ganas de responder: "No hay nada especial y no ha pasado nada de particular" (bueno, quizás hubiera sido mejor "no pasó nada", pero es que el pretérito perfecto simple no me salía de forma natural en una situación como esta). Pero no lo decía,  ¡eh!, sólo lo pensaba.

Creo haber oído esta expresión, "¿qué pasó?", a personas procedentes de países hispanoamericanos en el momento en que están saludando, pero no sé de cuáles. ¿Sabríais explicarme dónde se usa?

He encontrado esta [página web](https://www.spanishlearninglab.com/saludos-y-despedidas-en-espanol/) en la que se explica que el uso de preguntas como "¿qué pasó?", "¿qué hay?" o "¿qué nota?" para saludar varía de un país a otro, pero no especifica en qué países se usa cada una de ellas.

Answer (score 3):

Vamos a hacer una lista colaborativa de países y regiones donde se usa este saludo.

- Canarias
- México
- Estados Unidos
- León (España)
- ?

Comment: ¡Perfecto, @aparente001!

Comment: Como curiosidad, en hebreo también se usa "¿qué pasó?" (ma kará, ?מה קרה ) como saludo.